# StyleCopのコードクリーニング設定でvarキーワード使用のオプションがあり、varキーワード使用すべきなのか？

Tags: c#

StyleCopのコードクリーニング設定でvarキーワード使用のオプションがありますが、現在社内でこの設定をしています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

私が最初に設定したのではないので、なぜ、常にVarを使用するかは分かりません。知っているのはvarを使用する際にコードが読みやすいこと。ネットで検索をしたら、[stackoverflow本家にちょっと似たような質問を見つけました](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp)

結構面白い話題なので、varキーワード常に使用すべきかどうか、国内の開発者の意見を聞きたいです。

Comment: StyleCopは話題のきっかけでしかなく、varキーワード使用の是非を聞いているという事で合ってますか？

Answer (score 6):

個人的にvarを常用しています。
但し､以下の場合は推論型ではなく、明示的な型の利用を検討しています。

1. ラムダ式とDelegateの組み合わせ
2. blogなどの記事にする際のサンプルコード

1.に関しては、ラムダ式をvar で受けることができませんので､いずれかの書き方になります｡

```
var binOp=(Func<int,int,int>)((x,y)=>x+y);
Func<int,int,int> binOp=(x,y)=>x+y;
```

個人的には前者より後者の方が可読性が上で、余計なブラケットがない分書きやすいと考えているので､上記の場合はvarを使うことはあまりないです。

2.に関しては、記事内のサンプルで使ってしまうと、見ている側の理解の妨げになると思いますので､極力型を明示した形にしていることが多いです。
ただ、リテラルが直近で代入されているなど明らかな場合はvarを使ってしまうこともあるのでこの辺は割とゆるふわです。

私感ですが、この辺の影響は局所的なので、規約があればそれに従うし、無ければ無くてもそんな酷いことにはならないかな？とは思います。

Answer (score 4):

本家でロックされている質問を持ち込むのはどうかと思いますが、var常用者として型推論を使わないケースを挙げておきます。

- ジェネリックでない`IEnumerable`の列挙時

例) Windows Forms

```
foreach(Control c in Controls) // 型推論不能だがキャストは可能
```

- 後でアップキャストした値を再設定する場合

例) Entity Frameworkの検索時

```
IQueryable<Hoge> q = new SomeDbContext().TableHoge; // DbSet<Hoge>
if(fuga != null)
    q = q.Where(_ => _.Fuga == fuga); // IQueryable<Hoge>
```

- `T`等の型名が短い場合

Answer (score 1):

基本的には、常にvarキーワードを使用します。
しかし、数値を扱う型、int,long,doubleなどは、varよりも、型名をそのまま指定したほうが
良い場合もあります。